# Show value from an sql table to moodle messaging system

Tags: moodle, messaging

Is there any idea how to start writing some code to display an arithmetic value or string from an SQL Table to the moodle messaging system?

Comment: Do you mean in a message, as written by another user? ... or something else? (This question needs more details)

Comment: Sorry for not providing the whole story here. I would like to show a message which will contain a certain arithmetic value or a string from a table of the moodle DB. Not from a user to another user. Just a message that contains something from a table in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on that last comment, I'd say that no, there are no hooks to have an operation performed when a message is displayed.

It's definitely possible to [programmatically create a message](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Message_API) or a notification, but its content is static once created.